# How to add reference to Visual project with NuGet package?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, powershell, dll, nuget

I'd like to add a dll to my nuget package... In fact I don't want it to be "added" but just "referenced".
I don't want this file to be copied into the project where I install my package, I just want to add a reference that point to the dll file store into an other folder in my PC or a shared folder.
I'm a real beginner in powershell so I don't really know if I can do that with it...
I tried to use dll.refresh files but it seems it's not the good way to do in Visual Studio 2013.
I also tried to specify my external path in a file tag in the nuspec file, but it seems it's not possible to reference a dll without copying it...
I looked for Powershell scripts to help me but nothing does what I want to do.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I'll answer my own question.
After digging a bit more into Powershell, here is the way to do that:
install.ps1:

```
param($installPath, $toolsPath, $package, $project)

$newRef = $project.Object.References.Add("PathToMyDLL");
```

uninstall.ps1:

```
param($installPath, $toolsPath, $package, $project)

Remove-LibraryReference  $project.Name MyDLLName
```